# How do I get the symmetric intersection between Python sets?

Tags: python, set

I've been learning about Python sets recently. Let's say we have two sets:

```
set1 = {'dog', 'cat', 'hamster'}
set2 = {'monkey', 'dog'}
```

I know how to get the symmetric difference:

```
>>> set1.symmetric_difference(set2)
{'hamster', 'cat', 'monkey'}
```

But how do I get the symmetric intersection?

```
>>> set1.symmetric_intersection(set2)
...
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'symmetric_intersection'
```

Comment: What would you expect the result to be? I don't think there is such a thing as "symmetric intersection", generally. You probably just want `.intersection` (`set1 & set2`) or non-symmetric difference (`.difference` or `set1 - set2`)

Comment: @sytech april foolz

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "symmetric intersection" for set operations, in Python or generally in mathematics/set theory.

The available set operations between two sets that result in a new set are `union`, `intersection`, `difference` and `symmetric_difference`.

| Operation | Equivalent | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s.union(t) | s | t | new set with elements from both s and t |
| s.intersection(t) | s & t | new set with elements common to s and t |
| s.difference(t) | s - t | new set with elements in s but not in t |
| s.symmetric_difference(t) | s ^ t | new set with elements in either s or t but not both |

Between these operations, all the possible relationships between 2 sets are covered.